# paypal express checkout payment limit

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

The paypal express checkout API docs state that the 'Total cost of the transaction to the buyer' (PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT) cannot exceed 10,000 USD. See here...

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP

I was hoping to implement Express Checkout for a luxury e-commerce website where many items do exceed 10,000 USD.

Is there anyway to increase the Paypal Express payment limit? Presumably, many items sell through paypal on eBay for over 10,000 USD.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Paypal Customer Service. If the account qualifies, they can raise the limit.